# Performance of Google Desktop Search on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-desktop-search

I have read that that installing Google Desktop Search on Vista can slow down the computer because Vista already has a search indexing feature, and adding Google's separate indexing feature results in a performance hit. (Google hints at this in their FAQ [here](http://desktop.google.com/gettingstarted.html#vista).) Does this problem also exist in Win 7? Is there a workaround that improves performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Google Desktop on Windows 7 but I would suggest you try it out with the Windows indexer disabled. Hit Winkey+R, type services.msc, find Windows Search in the list, right click and hit properties, change startup type to disabled and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

RexE,

Windows 7 improves the users experience by changing the way performance is delivered (I.E. Resource consumption). To learn more about Windows 7, please see the following link: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Optimize-Windows-7-for-better-performance